# Blinking background color animation

Tags: css

I'm trying to create sort of blinking element animation. It should last one second - half second it has red border and green BG, and another half second green border and red BG. The change of colors should be just about immediate.

I tried it like this:

```
0, 49%, 99%, 100% {
    background-color: rgb(117,209,63);
    border: 3px solid #e50000;
}
49%, 50%, 99% {
    background-color: #e50000;
    border: 3px solid rgb(117,209,63);
}
```

It sort of worked, but the color transition was very slow. I tried also this:

```
0%, 49% {
    background-color: rgb(117,209,63);
    border: 3px solid #e50000;
}
49%, 50% {
    background-color: #e50000;
    border: 3px solid rgb(117,209,63);
}
50%, 99% {
    background-color: #e50000;
    border: 3px solid rgb(117,209,63);
}
99%, 100% {
    background-color: rgb(117,209,63);
    border: 3px solid #e50000;
}
```

and this:

```
0%, 50% {
    background-color: rgb(117,209,63);
    border: 3px solid #e50000;
}
50%, 99% {
    background-color: #e50000;
    border: 3px solid rgb(117,209,63);
}
```

But nothing worked as expected... Any help, please?

Comment: When I see right you have said your animation what to do but not how long it should last. Take a look at this page. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/keyframe-animation-syntax/

Comment: @MarcelWasilewski Actually I did say it - the animation should last 1 second. `animation: myAnim 1s infinite`

Comment: Take a look at this, for me this looks pretty quick: https://jsfiddle.net/wydmsfj0/ ... it would be good to see more of your code i think

Comment: You did everything right other than let the frames overlap. For example, in the last one you have two rules for 50% and so the last one wins. This essentially makes the color change from 0 - 50% (slow). Instead, all you needed to do was make the keyframes as `0%, 50%` and `50.1%, 99%` (or give a 1% split like in Marcel's snippet). The other thing to note, is the frames should always be `%`. Even `0` should be represented as `0%` or `from` and not `0`.

Comment: @MarcelWasilewski Yes, that's exactly what I needed! Could you please post it as an answer so I could accept it? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Take a look at this. [This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wydmsfj0) should be pretty accurate:

```css
.quadrat {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  -webkit-animation: NAME-YOUR-ANIMATION 1s infinite;  /* Safari 4+ */
  -moz-animation: NAME-YOUR-ANIMATION 1s infinite;  /* Fx 5+ */
  -o-animation: NAME-YOUR-ANIMATION 1s infinite;  /* Opera 12+ */
  animation: NAME-YOUR-ANIMATION 1s infinite;  /* IE 10+, Fx 29+ */
}

@-webkit-keyframes NAME-YOUR-ANIMATION {
  0%, 49% {
    background-color: rgb(117, 209, 63);
    border: 3px solid #e50000;
  }
  50%, 100% {
    background-color: #e50000;
    border: 3px solid rgb(117, 209, 63);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="quadrat"></div>
```

Comment: Super late, I know, but could you explain why this results in a »blinking« animation? :)

Comment: @JoSch it starts at 0% with green and keeps it until 49%. Then, instantly at 50% (the next frame) it switches to red, and keeps it until the end (100%). Each percentage means "do this at this keyframe position" :)

Comment: > "[…] 49%. Then, instantly at 50% (the next frame)" this might be true for short animations and/or really slow frame rate.  Technically it is not correct statement. 100 seconds long animation will have visible transition between 49% and 50% that will take one entire second.

Answer (score 15):

Hard to guess what is your desired behaviour, but few notes:

- You do not have to use duplicate keyframes and *very close percentages* to achieve "bouncing": just use `animation-direction: alternate;`.
- If you want to skip gradual transition completely, you can use `animation-timing-function:` **`step-end`** (or `steps(1,end);` but you have to move your "target" state to the "middle" keyframe).
- Or you can make transition very quick using very steep bézier curve, such as [`cubic-bezier(.8,0,.2,1)`](http://cubic-bezier.com/#.8,0,.2,1) or `1,0,0,1` - with short duration it is quite indistinguishable from discrete states.

```css
@keyframes anim-half {
  50% {
    background-color: #e50000;
    border-color: #75D13F;
    border-right-width: 4.8em;
  }
}

@keyframes anim {
  to {
    background-color: #e50000;
    border-color: #75D13F;
    border-right-width: 4.8em;
  }
}

p {
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  background-color: #75d13f;
  border: .2em solid #e50000;
}

/* just some fancyness */
p { border-style: solid; color: #fff; text-shadow: 0 0 3px #000; margin: 0 0 0.5em 0; }
p::after { content: attr(style); white-space: pre-wrap; }
```

```html
<p style="animation-name: anim-half;
animation-timing-function: step-end;"></p>

<p style="animation-name: anim;
animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(1,0,0,1);"></p>

<p style="/* linear reference */
animation-name: anim;
animation-timing-function: linear;"></p>
```

Comment: `border` shorthand can be animated because even though it is a short-hand way of writing the UA interprets it as those three long hand which you have mentioned only. Secondly, the snippet is providing what exactly the OP did not want - which is a slow transition (gradual). If my interpretation of the question is correct, what they are looking for is a hard/immediate change.

Comment: Oh, you are right, I expressed it really bad, I meant you cannot change implicit `border-style: none` to some other value in keyframe, but as you say you can use shorthand in keyframe to animate other `border-*` properties, and it is really rendered if initial ..style was other than `none`.

Answer (score -3):

Refinement of the code already presented by the previous friend

```
.blink {
    animation-duration: 0.5s;
    animation-iteration-count: 2;
    animation-direction: alternate;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
}
.blink-default {animation-name: anim-default;}
.blink-primary {animation-name: anim-primary;}
.blink-success {animation-name: anim-success;}
.blink-info {animation-name: anim-info;}
.blink-warning {animation-name: anim-warning;}
.blink-danger {animation-name: anim-danger;}

@keyframes anim-default {
    to {color: #333;background-color: #fff;}
}
@keyframes anim-primary {
    to {color: #fff;background-color: #337ab7;}
}
@keyframes anim-success {
    to {color: #fff;background-color: #5cb85c;}
}
@keyframes anim-info {
    to {color: #fff;background-color: #5bc0de;}
}
@keyframes anim-warning {
    to {color: #fff;background-color: #f0ad4e;}
}
@keyframes anim-danger {
    to {color: #fff;background-color: #d9534f;}
}

<p class="blink blink-primary">example linear</p>
```